# JQuery modification of a nested unordered list

Tags: jquery, html-lists

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

I've used JQuery to add `>` elements next to every `<li>` with a nested `<ul>` allowing an indication that the has a nested menu.

I'm trying to take the `href` attributed the out of the `<li>` with a nested `<ul>` and create (as the first item in the nested menu) an `Overview` menu item.

For example:

```
• Phones
    - Overview
    - Phone Types
    - Phone FAQs
```

The menu is created with the Overview link on the `Phones` parent, and the `Overview` link is to be dynamically created.

Here's what I have currently:

```
$('li.menu-item').each(function(index){
        if($(this).children('ul').length>0){
            var theHref = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
            var ulContent = $(this).children('ul').html();
            $(this).children('a').attr('href', '#');
            $(this).children('ul').html('<li><a href="'+theHref+'">Overview</a></li>'+ulContent);
            $(this).append('<div class="menu-ticker"><a class="ticker">></a></div>');
        }
    });
```

`menu-ticker` is referring to the `>` element.

My error is that (using the example above) Phone Types has a nested menu too. However, once I've added the `Overview` link, the `>` doesn't appear on sub-sub menus. Without the `Overview` code, it works fine.

Can anybody help?

**UPDATE:**
As requested, here's a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/wGKQh/

Comment: Could you put it on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution was staring me in the face, because I'd ripped out the html, into a variable then re-added it with an addition, the selectors hadn't targeted that which I'd modified.

Instead of this, I used prepend.

```
$('li.menu-item').each(function(index){
        if($(this).children('ul').length>0){
            var theHref = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
            $(this).children('a').attr('href', '#');
            $(this).children('ul').prepend('<li><a href="'+theHref+'">Overview</a></li>');
            $(this).append('<div class="menu-ticker"><a class="ticker">></a></div>');
        }
    });
```